# #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'WHERE est.tutor = doc.ID_docente LIMIT 0, 25' en la linea 2

Tags: mysql, sql

mi codigo es el siguiente considere que la consulta era la adecuada pero al parecer existe algun error

```
Select est.ID_estudiante, est.nombres as nombre_est, est.tutor, doc.ID_docente, doc.nombres nombre_doc FROM estudiante est LEFT JOIN docente doc 
WHERE est.tutor = doc.ID_docente;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al usar `LEFT JOIN`, necesitas `ON` en lugar de `WHERE`:

```
Select est.ID_estudiante, est.nombres as nombre_est, est.tutor, doc.ID_docente, doc.nombres nombre_doc
  FROM estudiante est LEFT JOIN docente doc 
    ON est.tutor = doc.ID_docente;
```

Comment: me has salvado la vida gracias si funciono.